# speeding up nested for loop in R

Tags: r, json, loops, parsing, lapply

I have a nested for loop that I am using to parse a complex and large json file. It takes forever! I am wondering if there is a way to speed this up that I am missing? I can link to a smaller json file if that would be useful? Not sure if something from the apply family would be of use?

```
for(row_n1 in 1:length(json_data$in_network)){
  in_network1=json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]
  in_network1[["negotiated_rates"]]=NULL
  in_network_df=as.data.frame(in_network1)
  
  for(row_n2 in 1:length(json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]$negotiated_rates)){
    reporting=NULL
    for(row_n3 in 1:length(json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]$negotiated_rates[[row_n2]]$provider_groups)){
      npi_df=as.data.frame(toString(json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]$negotiated_rates[[row_n2]]$provider_groups[[row_n3]]$npi))%>% set_names(nm = "npi")
      tin_df=as.data.frame(t((json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]$negotiated_rates[[row_n2]]$provider_groups[[row_n3]]$tin)))
      df=merge(npi_df,tin_df)
      df=merge(in_network1,df)
      reporting=rbind(reporting,df)
    }
    negotiated_prices_df=NULL
    for(row_n3 in 1:length(json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]$negotiated_rates[[row_n2]]$negotiated_prices)){
      df=as.data.frame(t((json_data$in_network[[row_n1]]$negotiated_rates[[row_n2]]$negotiated_prices[[row_n3]])))
      negotiated_prices_df=bind_rows(negotiated_prices_df,df)
    }
    r=merge(reporting,negotiated_prices_df)
    result=bind_rows(result,r)
    
  }
  if(row_n1%% 100 ==0)
    print(paste (row_n1,Sys.time() ,sep="====="))
}  

l=json_data
l$in_network=NULL

result=merge(as.data.frame(l),result)
```

This isn't a big deal on small files (e.g., < 1,000 rows in the result df, but when I am dealing with 1m+ it just takes forever!)

Comment: Binding inside loops is always inefficient. Better to construct separate entities within the loop and then bind at the end. The tidyverse makes this easy because `bind_rows()` and `bind_cols()` both take a list as their argument, whereas `rbind()` and `cbind()` do not. That fits well with using `lapply`.

Comment: Limey, can you explain a bit more? I'm not the most skilled in R...ask you might have been able to tell haha. Do you mean basically remove as.data.frame from each loop and just doing bind_rows() and bind_cols() at the end of the loop instead?

Comment: It's impossible to provide definitive advice without both test data and expected output.  The code you are using is straightforward, but your data structure is complex.  How can you expect us to validate solutions without both a defined starting point and a target to aim at?  There are many, many examples on stackoverflow of converting `for` loops to the `apply` family of functions.  Take a look at those.